# Textfield validation in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I am working on Flutter `TextField` widget. I want to show an error message below the `TextField` widget if the user does not fill that `TextField`. I only have to use `TextField` Widget not `TextFormField` in this case.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/validation_textformfield

Answer (score 191, accepted):

A Minimal Example of what you Want:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyHomePageState createState() {
    return new MyHomePageState();
  }
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _controller = TextEditingController();
  bool _validate = false;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('TextField Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Error Showed if Field is Empty on Submit button Pressed'),
            TextField(
              controller: _controller,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Enter the Value',
                errorText: _validate ? "Value Can't Be Empty" : null,
              ),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  _validate = _controller.text.isEmpty;
                });
              },
              child: Text('Submit'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: this shows "invalid constant value" error on line `errorText: _validate ? 'Value Can\'t Be Empty' : null,`

Comment: @RezaMortazavi delete const before InputDecoration

Comment: Let's make some clean code in the example in `setState`: `_validate = _text.text.isEmpty`

Answer (score 43):

Flutter handles error text itself, so we don't require to use variable `_validate`. It will check at runtime whether you satisfied the condition or not.

```dart
final confirmPassword = TextFormField(
  controller: widget.confirmPasswordController,
  obscureText: true,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock_open, color: Colors.grey),
    hintText: 'Confirm Password',
    errorText: validatePassword(widget.confirmPasswordController.text),
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0),
  ),
);

String validatePassword(String value) {
  if (!(value.length > 5) && value.isNotEmpty) {
    return "Password should contain more than 5 characters";
  }
  return null;
}
```

**Note**: User must add at least one character to get this error message.

Comment: This is using - `TextFormField` Question is about without using - `TextFormField`.

Comment: @anmol.majhail: Added more info related to TextFormField which would be helpful for others.

Comment: I confirmed that it also works with TextField wrapped by FormField. @jitsm555 could refactor it for a better answer.

Comment: works with `TextField` without even wrapping with the FormField as well, just changing the seems like they can be used interchangeably or there are very few differences

Comment: @jitsm555 this is looking great but how should we call the validatePassword method from the on pressed method of the RaisedButton ?

Comment: Getting: value of type 'Null' can't be returned from the method 'validatePassword' because it has a return type of 'String'.

Answer (score 40):

I would consider using a `TextFormField` with a `validator`.

Example:

```
class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('TextFormField validator'),
      ),
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Enter text',
              ),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              validator: (text) {
                if (text == null || text.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Text is empty';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                  // TODO submit
                }
              },
              child: Text('Submit'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 24):

- If you use `TextFormField` then you could easily implement 'Error
  below your text fields'.
- You can do this without using `_validate` or any other flags.
- In this example, I have used `validator` method of `TextFormField`
  widget. This makes the work a lot more easier and readable at the
  same time.
- I also used `FormState` to make the work more easier

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final _form = GlobalKey<FormState>(); //for storing form state.

//saving form after validation  
void _saveForm() {
    final isValid = _form.currentState.validate();
    if (!isValid) {
      return;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Form(
          key: _form, //assigning key to form

          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[

              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Full Name'),
                validator: (text) {
                  if (!(text.length > 5) && text.isNotEmpty) {
                    return "Enter valid name of more then 5 characters!";
                  }
                  return null;
                },
              ),

              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email'),
                validator: (text) {
                  if (!(text.contains('@')) && text.isNotEmpty) {
                    return "Enter a valid email address!";
                  }
                  return null;
                },
              ),

              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Submit'),
                onPressed: () => _saveForm(),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**I hope this helps!**

Comment: This should be the only acceptable answer. The rest of the answers all seem to be sub-solutions. This solution can actually be used to validate a larger form. Thanks

Comment: But he explicitly said, he needn't a `TextFormField`

Answer (score 4):

For TextFiled and TextFormFiled Validation you can use this Example I hope this will helpful for you people.

```
                   TextField(
                          enableInteractiveSelection: true,
                          autocorrect: false,
                          enableSuggestions: false,
                          toolbarOptions: ToolbarOptions(
                            copy: false,
                            paste: false,
                            cut: false,
                            selectAll: false,
                          ),
                          controller: _currentPasswordController,
                          obscureText: passwordVisible,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            errorText: Validators.password(
                                _currentPasswordController.text),
                            filled: true,
                            fillColor: Colors.white,
                            contentPadding:
                                const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 24, 12, 16),
                            border: const OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0))),
                            // filled: true,
                            labelText: 'Password',
                            hintText: 'Enter your password',
                            suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  passwordVisible = !passwordVisible;
                                });
                              },
                              child: Container(
                                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(13),
                                  child: Icon(
                                      passwordVisible
                                          ? FontAwesomeIcons.eyeSlash
                                          : Icons.remove_red_eye_sharp,
                                      color: ColorUtils.primaryGrey,
                                      size: 25)),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
```

Validation Message Example Code

```
static password(String? txt) {
if (txt == null || txt.isEmpty) {
  return "Invalid password!";
}
if (txt.length < 8) {
  return "Password must has 8 characters";
}
if (!txt.contains(RegExp(r'[A-Z]'))) {
  return "Password must has uppercase";
}
if (!txt.contains(RegExp(r'[0-9]'))) {
  return "Password must has digits";
}
if (!txt.contains(RegExp(r'[a-z]'))) {
  return "Password must has lowercase";
}
if (!txt.contains(RegExp(r'[#?!@$%^&*-]'))) {
  return "Password must has special characters";
} else
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**We can validate user-input in `TextField` by simply over-riding selected parameters in the `InputDecoration` widget**

Note: Although using the validation methods([save](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FormState/save.html), [reset](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FormState/reset.html), [validate](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FormState/validate.html)) defined in the [`FormState`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FormState-class.html) object is a popular option for validating forms, this may not be an efficient way.

From the official documentation of [GlobalKey](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GlobalKey-class.html):

> **GlobalKeys should not be re-created on every build. They should usually be long-lived objects owned by a State object**, for example.
> Creating a new GlobalKey on every build will throw away the state of the subtree associated with the old key and create a new fresh subtree for the new key. Besides harming performance, this can also cause unexpected behavior in widgets in the subtree. For example, a GestureDetector in the subtree will be unable to track ongoing gestures since it will be recreated on each build.

The following example shows a simple way of validating the amount entered in field using `errorText`, `errorStyle`, and `errorBorder` parameters.

I am using flutter version: 3.10.0

```
                TextField(
                  inputFormatters: [
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],

                  onChanged: (value) {
                    // This method verifies and validates the user-input based on the conditions defined in it.
                    amountErrorStatus = validateAmount(value);

                    if (!amountErrorStatus) {
                      amountTextEditingController.text = value;

                     // Code to utilise the validated input.   
                    }
                    
                  },
                  controller: amountTextEditingController,
                  decoration: inputDecoration(
                    contentPadding:
                        const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                  ).copyWith(

                   // Based on the boolean status indicated by `amountErrorStatus`,
                   // you can choose to display the error message and error border.
                    errorText: amountErrorStatus
                        ? "Your redeem amount cannot be lesser than ₹ 500."
                        : null,
                    errorStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      color: Colors.red[700],
                    ),
                    errorBorder: amountErrorStatus
                        ? OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: colors.red[400],
                              width: 1.5,
                            ),
                          )
                        : OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.gray[300],
                              width: 1.5,
                            ),
                         ),
                    ),
                )


void validateAmount(String value) {
bool amountErrorStatus = false;

  if (value.isEmpty) {
    amountErrorStatus = true;
  } 
  else if ((int.tryParse(value) ?? 0) < 500) {
    amountErrorStatus = true;
  } 
  else {
    amountErrorStatus = false;
  }
return amountErrorStatus;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
AppTextField(
                        hintText: "Password",
                        prefixIcon: Icons.key,
                        suffixIcon: loginController.visibility.value ? Icons.visibility_off : Icons.visibility,
                        controller: loginController.password.value,
                        obscureText: loginController.visibility.value,
                        onTap: (){
                          loginController.visibility.value =! loginController.visibility.value;
                        },
                        validator: (value){
                          if(loginController.password.value.text.isEmpty){
                            return "Please Enter Your Password";
                          }else if(loginController.password.value.text.length < 8){
                            return "Please Enter 8 Digits";
                          }else{
                            return null;
                          }
                        },
                      ),
```

Comment: There are **six existing answers** to this question, including a top-voted, accepted answer with nearly **two hundred votes**. Are you _certain_ your solution hasn't already been given? If not, why do you believe your approach improves upon the existing proposals, which have been validated by the community? Offering an explanation is _always_ useful on Stack Overflow, but it's _especially_ important where the question has been resolved to the satisfaction of both the OP and the community. Help readers out by explaining what your answer does different and when it might be preferred.