# Custom Validation TextFormField Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have Form and TextFormField inside it :

```
 new Expanded(
  child: TextFormField(
    style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
    validator: (String value) {
      if (value.length <= 5) {
       //Show error as a Snackbar
      }
    },
    onSaved: (String value) {},

  ),
)
```

On a Buttom press I am checking if all the fields are validate :

```
 if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      _submit();
 }
```

Now the issue is when you call `validate()` and don't return any text in `validate()` method then it will consider it return true.

I don't want to show error below the textField but as a Snackbar.

Also, I tried setting an extra flag and setting in each validator Method but it gets complex if there are multiple fields in the form.

Can anyone tell me how can I handle this situation where `_formKey.currentState.validate()` should return false and validator method
inside TextFormField need not to return error text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be using **Form** widget and **TextFormField** for displaying error in TextField.

Do validation by controllers instead

For Example

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyHomePageState createState() {
    return new MyHomePageState();
  }
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _text = TextEditingController();
  bool _validate = false;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _text.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('TextField Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Error Showed if Field is Empty on Submit button Pressed'),
            TextField(
              controller: _text,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Enter the Value',
              ),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                        if(_text.text.length<=5){
                    // open dialog
                  }
              },
              child: Text('Submit'),
              textColor: Colors.white,
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: And what we can do with controllers ? just an empty check ?

Comment: You can also check length of string by controller.

Comment: Controller provide TextField value

Comment: Why there is the setState ?

Comment: It is my requirement. Update answer please check

Comment: Updated answer please check

Answer (score 0):

I see that you want to validate the user-input in multiple form-fields but you don't want to display the error message below the form-field if the validation fails.

Firstly, the `_formKey.currentState.validate()` method validates **every** `TextFormField` wrapped as children within a `Form` widget as parent with `_formKey` as GlobaKey attached to it.

Secondly, `validate()` method returns *true* only if user-input passes **all** the conditions specified in the `validator` property for the respective form-field and returns false if any of them fails to satisfy.

With these two points in mind, it would be contradicting when we ask flutter to validate the form-field and to return false upon successful validation.

The solution for your 1st problem lies in the fact that the framework calls the [`onSaved()`][1] callack when it encounters `_formKey.currentState.save()`.
So, if you want to show a snackBar upon successful validation, write your logic within the onSaved() property.

As for the 2nd problem, you can just over-ride the `errorText`, `errorStyle`, and `errorBorder` properties in the `decoration` property of your `TextFormField` as per your requirements. For more info on this one refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76739149/19368196.

```
 new Expanded(
     child: TextFormField(
     style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
     keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
     decoration: InputDecoration(
     // Override the errorText and errorBorder as per your requirement.
       errorText: "",
       errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
      ),
     ),
     validator: (String value) {
      if (value.length <= 5) {
       // Just leave it empty as you don't wanna show any error text.
      }
     },
    onSaved: (String value) {
         // Show snackbar
        },
      ),
    )
```

On button press,

```
 if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
  _formKey.currentState.save();
 }
```

Hope this was helpful.