# The alignment of a TextFormField validation error message

Tags: flutter, dart, styles, alignment, textformfield

How can I change the alignment of a TextFormField validation error message?

```
TextFormField(
   textAlign: TextAlign.center,
   decoration: const InputDecoration(
      errorStyle: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 16.0,
      ),
   ),
   validator: (value) {
      if (value.isEmpty) {
         return 'Please enter some text';
      }
      return null;
    },
   ),
```

Current output:

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change the default validator, but try creating a custom one!

[Custom Validation TextFormField Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55282476/custom-validation-textformfield-flutter)

Answer (score 5):

Out of the box, this is most easily done with FormField (no package needed).
Since your error text is just a Text field in a column, you can put it anywhere you like, above, below, justified however you like.

```
final _formState = GlobalKey<FormState>();
var _textController = TextEditingController()

  Form(
    key: _formState,
    child: FormField(
        validator: (val) => val == null || val == '' ? 'Type Something!' : null,
        builder: (formFieldState) {
          return Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
            TextField(
                  controller: _textController,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Enter Something',
                  ),
                ),
            if (formFieldState.hasError)
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                child: Text(
                  formFieldState.errorText!,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
          ],
          );
        },
      ),
)
```

This works with a FormState, so if you do this with multiple fields, calling the `if (_formState.currentState!.validate()) {...` will activate all of them that fail.

Comment: This one is the best answer. Thank you! With this i can put validation error message wherever i want.

Comment: Thanks, I do wish they had called it FormFieldBuilder.

Answer (score 2):

It seems impossible for this time, there is an opened issue for this also
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21343

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Flutter form builder](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_form_builder) package you can create a custom field quite easily and add your error(using field.errorText) wherever you want, here it's at the top of the field. The widget will rebuild on error showing the error Text widget so you don't really have to take care of state management for this part.

Code snippet:

```
FormBuilderField<double>(
      name: 'testField',

      builder: (FormFieldState field) {
        return InputDecorator(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: InputBorder.none,
          ),
          child: InkWell(
            child: Column(
              children: [

                //notice how we add the textfield for the error here
                if (field.errorText != null)
                  Text(
                    field.errorText!,
                    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                  ),
                Text(
                  'Label',
                  style: context.customtextTheme.subtitle1,
                ),
                ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this code for the alignment error text.

```
bool isValid = true;
Container(
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
              height: isValid
                  ? Sizes().screenSize(context).height * 0.07
                  : Sizes().screenSize(context).height * 0.09,
              width: Sizes().screenSize(context).width * 0.7,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                BoxShadow(
                    color: isValid ? Colors.grey : Colors.transparent,
                    offset: const Offset(3, 4),
                    blurRadius: 7),
              ]),
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Form(
                    key: state,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: emailCTL,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      validator: (val) {
                        if (val!.isNotEmpty && isEmail(val)) {
                          return null;
                        }else{
                          return "";
                        }
                      },
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        isDense: false,
                        filled: true,
                        hoverColor: Colors.grey,
                        focusColor: Colors.grey,
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        hintText: "Email ID",
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        errorStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)),
                        enabledBorder:
                            OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                        errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)),
                        focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                        ),
                        prefixIcon: Icon(
                          Icons.email,
                          color: Colors.green,
                        ),
                        label: Text("Email",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.green,
                            )),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    bottom: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    child: isValid
                        ? Container()
                        : Text(
                            "Invalid Email ID",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                          ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),

 onTap: () {
                print(state.currentState!.validate());
                setState(() {
                  if (!state.currentState!.validate()) {
                    isValid = false;
                  } else {
                    isValid = true;
                  }
                });
              },
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can put spaces
look like
return '           Please enter some text';

Answer (score 0):

In Flutter 3.13.0 this has been resolved. By simply using the `error` property of **InputDecoration**, you can align your error message.

Note that the `validation` property is not compatible with the `error` property, so you have to provide a validation outside the **InputDecoration** to hide or show your error message.

*Code sample*

```dart
decoration: InputDecoration(
  error: _validateEmail(_controller.text),
),

Widget? _validateEmail(String? value) {

  String? errorText;
  late final textWidget = Align(
    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
    child: Text(
      errorText!,
      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 12),
    ),
  );

  if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
    errorText = 'Email is required';
    return textWidget;
  }

  if (!isEmailValid) {
    errorText = 'Invalid email address';
    return textWidget;
  }

  return null;
}
```

This also introduces a few issues. You would notice that the border colour and the cursor color do not change to red, you can solve this with

```dart
focusedBorder: (!isEmailVaid)
      ? OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
        )
       : someDefaultBoder,
```

You would also want to provide the same logic for `enabledBorder` or when the input field loses focus the red border will also be removed. This conditional also applies to the cursor colour.