# Android like Textfield Validation in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, textfield

I would like to achieve Android like `TextField` validation in `Flutter`.

I tried the `TextField` docs of `Flutter` and the `InputDecoration` has a property of `errorText` but is displays error at the bottom of `textfield`. I want to achieve something like below in Flutter

[image]

Comment: See [this](https://proandroiddev.com/easy-edittext-content-validation-with-kotlin-316d835d25b3)

Comment: @Sniffer I know how to do this in Native Android. My question is how to do this in Flutter?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53426227/8101634

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Textfield validation in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53424916/textfield-validation-in-flutter)

Comment: @primo This not what I want

Comment: @Sniffer No its not a duplicate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `TextFormField` along with a custom `Tooltip` inside a `Stack` to achieve this effect. In the `decoration` property for the `TextFormField` you can use the `suffixIcon` property of the `InputDecoration` class to pass the error icon.

And you can use a `bool` variable to show/hide the tooltip message when the validation error occurs.

Example code for the `TextFormField`:

```
  TextFormField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      //Set the different border properties for a custom design
      suffixIcon: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.error, color: Colors.red),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            showTooltip = !showTooltip; //Toggles the tooltip
          });
        },
      ),
    ),
    validator: (String value) {
      if(value.isEmpty) {
        setState(() {
          showTooltip = true; //Toggles the tooltip
        });
        return "";
      }
    }
  );
```

You can wrap the above code along with your custom tooltip widget code with a `Stack` to achieve the error tooltip effect.

Below is a quick working example. You can design your own custom tooltip widget and use it in your code.

Example:

```
class LoginAlternate extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginAlternateState createState() => _LoginAlternateState();
}

class _LoginAlternateState extends State<LoginAlternate> {

  GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey();
  bool showTooltip = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 100,
          vertical: 100
        ),
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                overflow: Overflow.visible,
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide.none
                      ),
                      suffixIcon: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.error, color: Colors.red,),
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            showTooltip = !showTooltip;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                      hintText: "Password"
                    ),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if(value.isEmpty) {
                        setState(() {
                          showTooltip = true;
                        });
                        return "";
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: 50,
                    right: 10,
                    //You can use your own custom tooltip widget over here in place of below Container
                    child: showTooltip
                    ? Container(
                      width: 250,
                      height: 50,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        border: Border.all( color: Colors.red, width: 2.0 ),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
                      ),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          "Your passwords must match and be 6 characters long.",
                        ),
                      ),
                    ) : Container(),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text("Validate"),
                onPressed: () {
                  _formKey.currentState.validate();
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about `ToolTip`

You can use this [library](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/super_tooltip) or Go through Flutter [doc](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Tooltip-class.html)

```
new Tooltip(message: "Hello ToolTip", child: new Text("Press"));
```

you can use the library  **super_tooltip #**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can customize this type of error by using overlay widget. Error can be shown with overlay widget and that error icon can be changed using inputDecoration of TextField.

Here is the link for understanding overlay widget--
https://medium.com/saugo360/https-medium-com-saugo360-flutter-using-overlay-to-display-floating-widgets-2e6d0e8decb9

Comment: Will give it a try and let you know