# Validator to TextField

Tags: validation, flutter, dart, textfield

How can I implement a validator to a TextField. I know TextFormField has a validator option, but I need the validator in a TextField. If the TextField value is not valid I need to decorate it, just like a TextFormField.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Textfield validation in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53424916/textfield-validation-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyHomePageState createState() {
    return new MyHomePageState();
  }
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _text = TextEditingController();
  bool _validate = false;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _text.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('TextField Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Error Showed if Field is Empty on Submit button Pressed'),
            TextField(
              controller: _text,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Enter the Value',
                errorText: _validate ? 'Value Can\'t Be Empty' : null,
              ),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  _text.text.isEmpty ? _validate = true : _validate = false;
                });
              },
              child: Text('Submit'),
              textColor: Colors.white,
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This code shows error text when the user don't enter anything in the TextField