# How to show AllertDialog if Textfield is empty in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm building an application on flutter and i have a problem because of the list.

In flutter, I made an empty list, in this list filling by users. An assignment takes place when the user enters a value, but this always happens when a value is entered. If no value is entered, it reflects the previous value in the list. What I want is for the program to create an Alertdialog if no string value is entered in the TextField.

Here is my List (TaskData)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuEC8.png)

And my TextField
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jtgd.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `errorText`:

Full [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53426227/14500144)

```dart
final _text = TextEditingController();

TextField(
  controller: _text,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: 'Enter the Value',
    errorText: _validate ? 'Value Can\'t Be Empty' : null, //here
  ),
),
```

Inside a Button use:

```dart
bool _validate = false;

RaisedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    setState(() {
      _text.text.isEmpty ? _validate = true : _validate = false;
    });
  },
  child: Text('Submit')    
  textColor: Colors.white,
  color: Colors.blueAccent,
),
```

Comment: Please choose one of the answers and [Accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

try this in your addTask method

```
void addTask() {
if (name = '') showMyAlertDialog();
else {nameList.add(name);
notifyListeners();}
name = ''; 
}
```

Comment: Also, its work too if someone wants to implement with provider this is the option